# Confirmation login dialog does not appear in facebook api, google+ api, vk api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, google-plus-signin

My question is a little broad, but in case someone had same is very possible.
After first launch facebook, google+ and vk.com asked me to confirm requested permission (for example, facebook: "public_profile, email, user_friends"). But every next time the confirmation dialog did not appear. I cleared cache, I reinstalled app, but still nothing. Maybe I lost something? Or facebook remembered device and doesn't ask confirmation second time? I still have information I requested, but without confirmation. Google+ even doesn't open its `Activity`, just straight away shows me the result. 
For example my facebook code.

My `GrahRequest` is same as in docs of facebook api and I execute it in `onSuccess()` callback which I added to `LoginManager`. Permissions I set to LoginManager aswell as: `LoginManager..getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(...)`.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
    accessToken,
    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(
               JSONObject object,
               GraphResponse response) {
            // my code
        }
    });
request.executeAsync();
```

Any explanation is very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the user accepts the permissions for an app, if the app asks for the same permissions from the same user, no re-confirmation will be needed. The only time another confirmation will be needed is if you ask for more permissions, or if the user has de-authorized the app from https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications.